# Replace middle of a string

Tags: java

I have a Address column in a csv file which I need to replace part of. It holds abbreviations of Street, Drive, Avenue, etc... I know the `replacedStr` is not the accurate way on doing this and I am running into problems using the below method. I have addresses such as `Stream Way St` which gets replaced into `Streetream Way Street`. How can I do this?

```
String str = "1234 Stack Overflow Dr";
String replacedStr = str.ReplaceAll("Dr","Drive");

System.out.println(str);
System.out.println(replacedStr);
```

Outputs:

```
1234 Stack Overflow Dr
1234 Stack Overflow Drive ----------- Requested
```

Comment: what problems you are facing? `str.replaceAll("Dr","Drive")` will work fine for your requirement

Comment: This sounds like a job for awk or sed.

Comment: I have addresses such as `Stream Way St` which gets replaced into `Streetream Way Street`.

Comment: Take a look at regex.

Comment: @Pons Did you like read the question?

Comment: I often do something like `if (str.endsWith(" Dr")) { str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 3) + " Drive"; }`

Comment: the replace is not the problem. the problem is which Dr to change to Drive and which Dr to leave as it is .. i.e the replace function has to be sentient .. regular expressions are your best bet in such cases

Comment: What if you have a street called `Dr Street` -- how should that be handled? This sort of task is asking for trouble when used with real data.

Comment: I have to replace the abbreviations and I am requesting your assistance. I searched the web could not get anything to match my criteria.

Comment: I think someone already pointed out Regex...

Comment: If you know how the address is stored (i.e. the first part is the house number, the second is the street name, and the last is the abbreviation), you can split it accordingly, replace only the abbreviation, and then put it back together. This might be easier than learning regular expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
String str = "1234 StaDrck Overflow Dr";
String replacedStr = str.replaceAll("\\bDr\\b","Drive");
```

another e.g.,

```
    String str = "Stream Way St";
    String replacedStr = str.replaceAll("\\bSt\\b","Street");


    System.out.println(str);
    System.out.println(replacedStr);
```

**Output**

'str' - Stream Way St

'replacedStr' - Stream Way Street

Comment: Thanks Pons for the help.

Comment: This approach does not work with e.g. "St Elmo's avenue" as an input string.

Answer (score 3):

Let's use a RegEx!

The regex `/\bDr\b/` should match what you need (replace Dr with St and Av if you need to match those). The java equivalent of this is `\\bDr\\b`

```
newString = oldString.replace("\\bDr\\b", "Drive");
```